# How can I send my data to an S3 Bucket using an AWS python3 Lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Pretty basic question I suppose so I apologize for a lack of experience on this end. I am using python3 to pull data from an api that retrieves a result in the following format:

```
{ 'id': <someid> '', 'firstname': <firstname>, 'Lastname': <lastname> }
```

As of right now I am just printing this JSON locally. I believe the easiest way for me to get this to an S3 Bucket is to use the following:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object

As of right now I am under the impression that it would perhaps look like the following?

```
    import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    region_name='us-east-1',
    aws_access_key_id=KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_KEY
)
content="String content to write to a new S3 file"
s3.Object('my-bucket-name', 'newfile.txt').put(Body=content)
```

Comment: Seems reasonable. Are you having a problem with this code? Also note that if this code is running in Lambda then assign an appropriate IAM role to the function so you don't have to explicitly provide access/secret keys to the boto3 SDK.

Comment: the problem I am now having is I am retrieving the json from an api  call and I actually do not need to store this in a txt file as I previously had.

Comment: Generally, just as an FYI, it's good to be clear what your questions are so that people aren't discouraged from answering. If they think you're simply stating something then their response will be "ok, doesn't appear to need additional help".